# Build something similar with Ethereum for what I have with Bitcoin

Tags: web3js

This is what I have and need with Bitcoin:
I use Blockcypher.com payment forward service,which generates a new unique Bitcoin address for a new members payment.
When I get paid with Bitcoin, Blockcypher.com makes a callback POST to my website URL identifying the member. 
From there I handle some logic in my VPS.

How could I build something similar with Blockcypher Ethereum service?
Generate unique address for customer.
Making a POST callback to my server when a payment has been received.